# File paths for java spark project deployed into Heroku

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku, spark-framework

I have deployed a java spark app onto Heroku but seem to be getting errors such as:

```
2017-02-16T22:17:35.519937+00:00 app[web.1]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/csvs/webApp/questions/questions.csv (No such file or directory)
```

I can't seem to locate my files. When I run the project locally in Eclipse (on windows), all is working well. What about the file paths do i need to change for the app to find the files when it is live. Sample code of the working local code:

```
String directory = "src/main/resources/csvs/webApp/questions/";
BufferedReader questions = null;
String line;
ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    questions = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + "questions.csv"));

    while ((line = questions.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!(line.equals("Question"))) {
            questionList.add(line);   
        }
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What deployment method are you using, `git push` or `heroku deploy:jar`? Can you confirm that the file exists by running `heroku run ls src/main/resources/csvs/webApp/questions/questions.csv`?

Comment: I am using heroku deploy and when I run `heroku run ls src/main/resources/csvs/webApp/questions/questions.csv` i get a doesn't exist error.

Comment: `heroku deploy` doesn't upload your `src/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `heroku deploy:war` and `heroku deploy:jar` commands do not upload your `src/` directory by default (the only uploads your WAR or JAR file respectively).

You can add the `--includes src` option to the `heroku deploy:*` commands.